# Can't PUT to source_blob.put_url using in Axios

Tags: node.js, heroku, axios

Having made a successful request to `https://api.heroku.com/sources`, I'm now attempting to upload a file to the `put_url` returned.

In postman this is working a treat.  However, when I attempt to do the same in Axios no good. I've attached a screenshot of the postman with the 200 status.

So far I've the following....

```
  const data = fs.readFileSync(zipPath, 'utf-8');

  var config = {
    method: 'put',
    url: put_url,
    headers: {
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
    },
    data,
  };

  await axios(config);
```

Which results in the following error `SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method`

I've played around with the encoding, and content types (pretty much stabbing in the dark tbh)

Annoyingly, I've got it working with this:

```
const post_data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'compare-api.tar.gz'));

  const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    hostname: host,
    path: put_url.substring(httpHost.length),
    headers: {
      Host: host,
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data),
    },
  };

  const req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function () {
      // Can't remove this even though it's doing nothing :(
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
      cb(null, source_blob);
    });

    res.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      cb(error);
    });
  });

  req.write(post_data, 'utf-8');
  req.end();
```

But I'd much rather it worked in Axios.

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

After what seemed like forever....

`'Content-Type': ''`

...did the trick!